# What kind of design I should go with

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We are developing a product which can be sold to multiple states.

The DB model will remain the same, but the business rules can change for entities.

For e.x:- To offer tax services, Georgia state might mandate that you have a CPA, other state might mark it optional.

How do we design such a system, where we can plug in any custom business logic for a given state.

what kind of design pattern will be useful here?

user

Comment: Maybe the [strategy pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) could work for you.

Comment: You may want to look at the Strategy and Decorator design patterns.  You might also consider a business rules engine.

Answer (score 1):

As functionality is the same for all states.
Then it's a matter of configuration. 
You could have lookup table for all states or different states depends on how much difference in rules between all states.
Then based on this configurations you can do your calculations if is this only your concern.

If functionality is different between states, then you have to handle this in OOP manner.

Comment: Functionality itself can be different. One state might require that we check with their web service to esnure that person has license info, other state might just require admin to update the data in a backend table.

Comment: Then you have to implement an abstract class for a State with basic functionality definition then override it or initialize it ineach state with its own rules "data" on runtime

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using an IoC (Inversion of Control) framework to be able to load the correct class implementing the desired business logic for each state.

An excellent IoC library for .NET is Autofac http://autofac.org/.  You should consider using Autofac modules which will allow you to create a module for each state in your system and this can be setup in a config file.